# getElementById returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, ejs

I can't get my DOM element to connect with my javascript and grab a "test" value.

**Client side**

```
<h1 id="redeem" value="test">Header 1</h1>
<script src="/javascripts/redeem.js"></script>
```

**Redeem.js**

```
const guest = document.getElementById('redeem').value;
console.log("redeeem.js working");
console.log(guest);
```

The `redeem.js working` text comes through but `guest` renders as `undefined`.

How do I get `test` to come through as my variable?

Comment: `h1` elements do not have a `value`. You should use the `innerText` property if you want the output "Header 1".

Comment: _"getElementById returning as undefined"_ - `.getElementById()` will never return `undefined`. It's either a `Element` or `null`.

Comment: Hi @RobinZigmond - I've entered text for a `value` so aren't I able to create a "value" this way?

Comment: @Andreas - it's rendering as `undefined`. I would send a screenshot if I could.

Comment: You already received the answer (and explanation) at the top of your question. I was only "nitpicking" that `.getElementById()` is not the problem. It's the `.value` property you try to access on the return value of `.getElementById()`

Comment: @econobro the `value` property is for inputs where the user can enter a value. See the question linked as a duplicate.